# Should "individuals" be singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm trying to figure out if "individuals" should have the s or no s at the end?

> ***Commit to Green*** inspires individuals to participate in initiatives that drive sustainable change.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it might be one way or the other?

Comment: Can you *count* "individuals"? Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 4):

The sentence means

> Commit to Green inspires people to act independently to participate in initiatives that drive sustainable change.

That is, it's inspiring many people. Plural. The sentence is correct as written.

Consider the alternative:

> Commit to Green inspires individual to participate in initiatives that drive sustainable change.

The meaning is wrong because it would be weird for an organization to exist just to inspire one person. It's also grammatically wrong because it would be missing the article "an" before "individual".